# Express Routes in a Single .js File

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Node/Express, and I think this is a simple ask, but I'm not quite if my logic/understanding is sound.

Here's a simplified version of my app structure:

```
/app
  /routes
    filter.js
    index.js
  app.js
```

I've got my routes defined in my app.js file like this.

```
// app.js

app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/filterone', require('./routes/filter'));
app.use('/filtertwo', require('./routes/filter'));
```

I'd like to point traffic from both */filterone* and */filtertwo* to my *filter.js* route, and then in the route I'd like to handle them like this:

```
// filter.js

router.get('/filterone', function(req, res, next) {
  // do something
}

router.get('/filtertwo', function(req, res, next) {
  // do something
}
```

Is that the correct way to go about doing this? Or should I be handling my routes differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the code you have will accomplish what you are trying to accomplish. When you do:

```
app.use('/filterone', require('./routes/filter'));
```

You are adding the routes you define in `filter.js` to your app's routes with `'/filterone'` pre-appended. Since you define a filter `'/filterone'` route (I assume this was in `filter.js`). This means to access the route you would need to query `/filterone/filterone`.

Andreas Rau's answer would work but if you want multiple route files you could just make one small addition.

```
//app.js

const express = require('express'),
      index = require('./routes/index')
      filters = require('./routes/filter'),
      app = express();

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/filter', filters);
```

This way you can access your filter routes with `/filter/route_name`. This will free you up to call different routes the same thing if they are in different route files. For example, you might want to show a filter and show something in your index. This way you can call them both show in their respective files and the index show route is `/show` and the filter show route is `/filter/show`.

Edit* Here is an example for your routes file's based on Andreas Rau's answer and using subroutes:

`routes/filter.js`:

```
const express = require('express'),
      router = express.Router();

router.get('/show',(req,res) => {
 //handle /filter/show
} );


router.get('/filterone',(req,res) => {
 //handle /filter/filterone
} );

router.get('/filtertwo',(req,res) => {
 //handle /filter/filtertwo
} );

module.exports = router;
```

`routes/index.js`:

```
const express = require('express'),
      router = express.Router();

router.get('/show',(req,res) => {
 //handle /show
} );

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: How would I account for multiple routes in my filter.js file then?

Comment: I added an example to my question, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense. Thanks morsecodist!

Answer (score 0):

```js
//filter.js

const express = require('express'),
      router = express.Router();

router.get('/',(req,res) => {
 //code...
} );


router.get('/filterone',(req,res) => {
 //code...
} );

router.get('/filtertwo',(req,res) => {
 //code...
} );

module.exports = router;
```

Now you can use it in your app.js code:

```js
//filter.js

const express = require('express'),
      router = require('./route/filter'),
      app = express();

app.use('/',router);
```

EDIT:
You can use multiple routers like this you just have to change the base path (first parameter of app.use)!
So basically you could create an index router, a filterone router and so on.

Answer (score 0):

both of your filterone and filtertwo are like subroutes from filter, so in your app you only need to:

```
app.use('/filter', require('./routes/filter'));
```

then inside your routes folder, you will create the filter.js file and slam the routes there

filter.js example:

```
var express= require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//optional if you want to use controllers or not
var controller = require('path to controller') 

//in case of controllers
router.get('/filterone', controller.funcToTakeCareOfFilterone);
router.get('/filtertwo', controller.funcToTakeCareOfFiltertwo);

//in case of no controllers
router.get('/filterone', function(req, res , next) {
  //your code
});
router.get('/filtertwo', function(req, res , next) {
 //your code
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I get a 404 for both routes when I try this method.